# Cannot access folders in Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have added new folders in Visual Studio Project Solution Explorer and stored C# WPF Pages in them but now in code i am not able to access that folder neither pages stored in it. Only one folder "medical_store" can be accessed. [Snapshot of solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEdBN.png)

Comment: access how? are there files in the folders? are you trying to fold out empty folders? did you put files into to folders? rightclick-add-class f.e.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been resolve. Actually Problem was simple that i forgot to add reference of Newly created folders in the WPF Pages namespaces.